# Java: How can I pass a value representing an Enum class?

Tags: java, class, generics, enums

Motivation: I would like to construct an enum that represents all possible values for some family of values (I hesitate to say "class" here). The enum will have additional methods, fields, and perhaps even implement other interfaces. I would then like to pass this enum to another method, where it will iterate over all of the possible values (using `Enum.values()` and do some work.

I've researched and found that enum `Foo` actually becomes `Foo extends Enum<Foo>`. This is why I cannot extend an enum. I have tried to define my method arguments as:

```
myMethod(Class<?> bar) {...}
myMethod(Class<? extends Enum> bar) {...}
myMethod(Class<? extends Enum<?>> bar) {...}
```

but inside the method when I try something basic like:

```
int i = bar.values().length;
```

it fails. Is there some other way I can do this (or avoid the need to do this)?

Note: I could pass an actual instance of the enum and use `bar.getDeclaringClass()` to find the enum class (rather than an instance) but this is pretty ugly.

Comment: It sounds like you're really describing an "iterator".

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe but the OP is looking for more than that. A Java enum works well as a logical universe of multitons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
<E extends Enum<E>> void myMethod(Class<E> enumType) {
    E[] values = enumType.getEnumConstants();
    ...
}
```

From the [`getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) documentation:

> Returns the elements of this enum class or null if this Class object
>   does not represent an enum type.

**Edit:** if you're using different enum types implementing a shared interface, you can modify your method in order to be able to call the interface methods. For example:

```
interface Fooable {
    void foo();
}

...

<E extends Enum<E> & Fooable> void myMethod(Class<E> enumType) {
    E[] values = enumType.getEnumConstants();
    for (E value : values) {
        value.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the bonus of a tutorial in generic methods and use of "&". I do plan to use enum types implementing other interfaces. The key to the OP is use of getEnumConstants() instead of values(). I took my previous attempts and substituted the former for the latter and that also worked. Why doesn't values() work? (and thank you)

Comment: Basically `values()` is a static method automagically declared for any `enum` type. But `bar` (or in my example `enumType`) isn't itself a type - it's an object representing a type, on which you can only call instance methods like `getEnumConstants()`.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there anything (maybe in the reflection package) that allows one to construct an object that can stand in for an actual class definition? Something like: MagicType standin; standin.makeClassFromMagicType(classArg).someStaticMethod();

Comment: To my knowledge that isn't possible - static methods can't be "proxied" like that because they have no interface. For example that syntax would require `makeClassFromMagicType` to return an instance of an interface declaring `someStaticMethod` - but of course the method couldn't be static then.